# How to activate a workbook that is open using the name of the workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have already a one workbook open but I am running a macro from another workbook. I would like to activate the first workbook using its name.

The code:

```
FileName = input_path_1 & input_file_1
Workbooks(FileName.xls).Activate
```

When I try to do so, it is giving me "Subscript out of range" error. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if your variable `Filename` contains the correct filename. (e.g. *Sample.xls*) 
Also check if `input_path_1` and `input_file_1` have correct values.
If they have it should be like this:

```
Workbooks(Filename).Activate
```

Now, if you need to append the extension name (e.g. `Filename` value is just *Sample*):

```
Workbooks(Filename & ".xls").Activate
```

The argument should always be in the form of string and should be the complete filename (with extension). Although numerals (index) is also accepted, you can't be sure what index refer to what workbook. Better yet, assign it to a variable.

```
Dim otherWB As Workbook
Set otherWB = Workbooks(Filename)
'Set otherWB = Workbooks(Filename & ".xls") '~~> for second scenario above
```

**Edit1:** From comment, if `Filename` contains the fullpath, then this might work.

```
Dim Filename1 As String
Filename1 = Split(Filename, "\")(UBound(Split(Filename, "\")))
Workbooks(Filename1).Activate
```

Comment: Mine contains .xls extension so I used the solution for the first one. But still it gives me subscript error. Runtime error 9.

Comment: @lakesh Try `Debug.Print Filename` if you'll get the same exact filename of the workbook. Also double check if the file extension is correct. (e.g. XL2007 and up have `.xlsx` extension.

Comment: Yes the variable value is correct. Because I used it to open the file.

Comment: It is in excel 2003. Might this be a problem.

Comment: @lakesh No problem in 2003. The problem may be this: `Because I used it to open the file` If you use it to open the file, then the string contains the full path (e.g. *C:\User\User.Name\Folder\Sample.xls*). You only need the *Sample.xls* part.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to access the window of the specific workbook is by below method

> Vba

```
Dim filename as string
set filename = Path.GetFileName(fullFilename)

set Workbook.Windows(filename).WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized
set Workbook.Windows(filename).WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal

' You can also use Worksheet.Activate() here if you want
```

> C#

```
string filename;
filename = Path.GetFileName(fullFilename);

Workbook.Windows[filename].WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized;
Workbook.Windows[filename].WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;

// you can also use Worksheet.Activate() here if you want
```

Comment: This a VBA question

Answer (score 0):

`Set OutsideWb = Workbooks("path + Filename.xlsm")` wont work if workbook already open

set a global wb variable to the opened file and use that
eg.

```
Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("path + Filename.xlsm") '
  Set OutsideWb = oXLBook 'prolly dont need oxlbook  todo
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2019,

`Workbooks(Filename).Activate` may not work if ".xlsx" is part of the variable name.
Example:  Filename = "123_myfile.xlsx" may not activate the workbook.

In this case, try:

`Filename = left(Filename,len(Filename)-5)` 'Filename now = "123_myfile"

`Workbooks(Filename & ".xlsx").Activate`