# Save and Close specific Excel

Tags: vbscript

I already create VBScript command for closing and saving an Excel file but it's not working for specific Excel file name (only close and save ActiveWorkbook).

Situation: 2 Excel files are open at the same time which is "DM.xlsx" and "Others.xlsx". What I need is too close and save only "DM.xlsx".

Here my current command:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objXL
On Error Resume Next
Set objXl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error Goto 0
On Error Resume Next
objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save
On Error Goto 0
objXL.Quit
On Error Goto 0
```

Is there an option to activate Workbook by its file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the particular workbook you want to save/close instead of the one that's currently active:

```
objXL.Workbooks("DM.xlsx").Save
objXL.Workbooks("DM.xlsx").Close
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers for answering my question. But tested both command and its doesn't seem to work at VBS.

Comment: @Falhuddin I don't have Excel at hand here, so I can't test. Perhaps you need "DM.xlsx" instead of just "DM".

Comment: Ok it's work. Absolute Brilliant. Thank You Very Much... :)

Comment: Activating an already opened workbook has [been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093294/692942), this is yet another variation of that.